# How to traverse a binary tree in a thread safe way?

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, thread-safety

I need a way to traverse a binary tree, using multiple threads and store elements that matches a criteria into a list.
How do I do that, in a thread safe way?

Comment: Does the tree change during the traversal, ie. changed by other threads? If so, then you need to identify the types of changes that could happen, and how you intend to mitigate that. For instance, if one thread is currently traversing deep in the tree, and another thread removes the entire subtree above that node, what should happen to the traversing thread then? Should it continue up until it completes the subtree that disappeared? Should it continue through the whole tree as it was when it started? Should it fail?

Comment: The tree doesn't change while traversing. I need to make ,traversing a typical binary tree,  more efficient by introducing multiple threads.

Comment: If the tree isn't changing, then what does thread safety have to do with anything?

Comment: @Stephen: I think the fact that he is writing to a list is why he needs it to be thread safe. The simple solution is not to share the list.

Comment: @Andre : well that's a different (and far simpler) question entirely! :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I'm going to put a lock in the list before writing and in the tree, an indicator stating whether the data had been written already or not.

Comment: @nsivakr: Do you have your answer?

Answer (score 6):

As SDG points out the answer depends a lot on the exact nature of your problem. If you want to decompose the traversal (i.e. traverse in parallel) then you can have threads acting on different sub-trees after say level 2. Each thread can then append to its own list, which can then be merged/concatenated at a join point. The simplest thing to do is to prevent mods to the tree while doing a traversal.

I just have to add that you don't keep firing off threads after you reach your level. You only do it once. So at level 2 you fire of a maximum of 4 threads. Each traveral thread treats it's subtree as its own rooted tree. You also don't do this unless you have a buttload of nodes, and a reasonably balanced tree. Buttload is a technical term meaning "measure". The part of the traversal up to the splitting point is traversed by the UI thread. If this was my problem I would think long and hard about what it was I needed to achieve, as it may make all the difference.

Let me add one more thing (is this becoming a Monty Python sketch?). You don't really need to concat or merge the result lists into a new list if all you need is to process the results. Even if you need the results ordered then it is still better to sort each list seperately (perhaps in parallel) and then "merging" them in a GetNextItem pull fashion. That way you don't need much additional memory. You can merge 4 lists at once in this fashion by having two "buffers" (can be pointers /indices to the actual entries). I'm trying to find a way to explain it without drawing a pic.

```
                     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   

             L1(0):  4 4 4 5 5 6 8 
    B1[L2,3]        \  
             L2[1]:  3 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9
 \   
             L3[1]:  2 2 4 4 5 5 6 8 
    B2[L3,2]          /
             L4[0]:  2 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 9
```

You keep pulling from whichever list satisfies the order you need. If you pull from B2, then you only need to update B2 and its sublists (in this case we pulled 2 from L3 and moved the L3's index to the next entry).

Comment: If I may add one point: the *most* threads that will run at one time is the number of CPU cores you have.  For most users that is "1" or "2" or (if you are really lucky) "4".  Splitting the problem into 32 threads doesn't help unless you have a huge, multi-cpu box.  In fact, too many threads will probably *slow down* the algorithm.
There are exceptions to this (where threads spend a lot of time waiting for i/o or something else) but in general it applies.

Comment: @Michael J: I agree. I don't know the specifics of his situation, which is why I said I would think long and hard about what it is I'm trying to solve. I have seen people try to use multiple threads, and Rube Goldberg logic, to "speed up" a recursive algorithm that could easily be sped up significantly by making it iterative and reusing results from a previous iteration. I believe one should understand the problem that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a few points that would help with an answer.

If the multiple threads are all read-only in their traversal, and the tree does not change for the duration of their traversal, and they all are putting those found matches into lists that those traversal threads own, then you should have no worries at all.

As you relax any of those constraints, you will need to either add in locking, or other appropriate means of making sure they play nicely together.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to lock the entry points of the binary tree class, and assume it's locked on the recursive traversal functions (for insertion, lookup, deletion).

If you have many readers and fewer writers, you can use `ReaderLocks` and `WriterLocks` to allow concurrent lookups, but completely lock on mutations.

If you want something finer grained, it will get much more complicated.  You'll have to define what you really need from "thread safety", you might have to pare down your binary tree API, and you'll probably need to lock nodes individually, possibly for the duration of a sub-tree traversal.